# When specifying command-line arguments Ruby no longer waits for input using gets

Tags: ruby

When running a ruby script with command line arguments, the "gets" is no longer blocking, it doesn't work.

test.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
puts "should wait for input"
gets
puts "test"
```

and here is how I run it

```
$ ./test.rb test.rb
  should wait for input
  test
```

It didn't wait.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 desktop, and Ruby from repository ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to STDIN.gets like others have recommended, you can use plain `gets` if you call `ARGV.clear` beforehand. The regular `gets` works as expected if there aren't command like arguments to the script, but if there are, then it will read them. It's not really clear why you're using `./test.rb test.rb`, but the second filename is a command line argument.

More specifically, if regular `gets` is called when ARGV is populated, then the result will be the *contents* of the file.

```
max@max ~> echo "content" > test.txt
max@max ~> ruby -e "puts ARGV.inspect; puts gets" test.txt
["test.txt"]
content
```

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind,

The "gets" actually takes the first line from the file I added in the cli arguments.

Very weird.

Comment: Aha, I was using different class "gets".. Thansk mate!

Comment: Yes, [`Kernel#gets`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) is quite different from [`IO#gets`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/IO.html#method-i-gets) even though they have similar functions and identical names.